# Property of Sequence Dense in $[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Suppose $\{x_i\}_{i = 1}^{\infty}$ is a dense sequence in the $[0,1]$ interval. For every $\epsilon > 0$, does there always exist an $n$ such that $|x_n-x_{n+1}| < \epsilon$?

Comment: Are you asking what you want to ask?  The only way for $|x_n-x_{n+1}|<\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon >0$ is if $x_n=x_{n+1}$.

Comment: I think he forget a "for all large enough $n$" in there. But it's still wrong, as my example below shows.

Comment: Maybe for all $\epsilon$, there exists $n$, such that...

Comment: @paw88789: I have edited my question.

Comment: @Hamou: I have edited my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even after thed edit, the answer's still no. Pick a sequence $y_i$ that's dense in $[0, 1/3]$. Let $x_{3i} = y_i$ and $x_{3i+1} = y_i + \frac{1}{3}$ and $x_{3i+2} = y_i + \frac{2}{3}$. Then the distance from  $x_n$ to $x_{n+1}$ is always at least $\frac{1}{3}$.

Answer (score 1):

No. Let the $x_i$ where $i = 0 \bmod 3$ be sent to the rationals by a dunumeration of them, while the other $x_i$s bounce back and forther between $-1$ and $1$.

Comment: I have edited my question.